# Is a better way to search DB when you have multiple combinations of the query?

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I try to think if there is a better way to do the following..
I have a form with 3 inputs and back in servlet I read them:

```
String input1= request.getParameter("input1");
String input2= request.getParameter("input2");
String input3= request.getParameter("input3");
```

I use `StringUtils.isBlank(input1)` to check if the user filled the input or not.
Now I want to ask my DB (I use `preparedStatements` to ask my DB(SQLITE) to get if there are records in a table with the combination of theses inputs.

So if the user fills only the 1st input, the query should be

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE INPUT1='input1'
```

if the user fills 2 inputs then the query should be

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE INPUT1='input1' AND INPUT2='input2'
```

and e.t.c

What I have done is

```
if(!StringUtils.isBlank(input1) && !StringUtils.isBlank(input2) &&  !StringUtils.isBlank(input3) ){  
    //search for input1+ input2+ input3
}else if(!StringUtils.isBlank(input1) && !StringUtils.isBlank(input2)){ 
    //search for input1 + input2
}//e.t.c
```

Is there a better way to do this, instead of writing down all the possible combinations of the query based on whether the input is filled or not? thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already using `StringUtils` then you could do something like this below:

```
private String extractWhereQueryPart(String input1, String input2, String input3) {
    List<String> sqlParts = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(input1)) {
        sqlParts.add(" INPUT1 = @input1 ");
    }

    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(input2)) {
        sqlParts.add(" INPUT2 = @input2 ");
    }

    // and so on

    if(sqlParts.isEmpty()) {
        return "";
    }

    return " WHERE " + StringUtils.join(sqlParts, " AND ");
}
```

This logic will be more straightforward in the end, because you don't need to do `if-else-if`. Just plain `if`s. And this approach is more supportable.

Comment: It works. Just replace with the `sqlParts.add(" machine = '"+input1+"'");`

Comment: Don't do this. This is dangerous. You are open to SQL-injection. It is better to replace it with `?` if you don't want to add `Declare` statement.

Answer (score 1):

There is always a question what "simpler" means but I think that the following is more readable:

1. Just make sure that your strings are either empty or contain something useful:

```java
String input1= StringUtils.stripToEmpty(request.getParameter("input1"));
String input2= StringUtils.stripToEmpty(request.getParameter("input2"));
String input3= StringUtils.stripToEmpty(request.getParameter("input3"));
```

2. In your SQL do all the checking:

```sql
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE (? = '' or INPUT1 = ?) AND (? = '' or INPUT2 = ?) AND (? = '' or INPUT3 = ?)
```

Comment: Can you explain me what the `(? = '' or INPUT1 = ?)` means?  the 1st `?` what is?

Comment: if ? is empty use this `INPUT1 = ?`  ?

Comment: ? Are indexed parameters for prepared statements. You should use them to protect yourself against SQL injections. In general it means that a parameter is inserted there. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html